# how to get headers from a CSV file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to validate headers in a CSV file before parsing data in it.

```
# convert the data into an array of hashes
CSV::Converters[:blank_to_nil] = lambda do |field|
  field && field.empty? ? nil : field
end
csv = CSV.new(file, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => [:all, :blank_to_nil])
csv_data = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
```

I know I can use headers method to get the headers

```
    headers = csv.headers
```

But the problem with [headers method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-headers) is it "Returns nil if headers will not be used, true if they will but have not yet been read, or the actual headers after they have been read."

So if I put `headers = csv.headers` above `csv_data = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }` line `headers` is `true` and if I put it after reading data, `headers` contain headers row in an array. It imposes an order of instructions on my method which is very hard to test and is bad programming.

Is there a way to read headers row without imposing order in this scenario? I'm using ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 32):

```
CSV.open(file_path, &:readline)
```

Comment: To clarify this solution, the above returns ONLY the array of headers:

    filepath = '/some/path/to/my.csv'
    CSV.open(filepath, &:readline)  # => ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']

Comment: No, it's equivalent to: ```CSV.open(file_path) { |csv| csv.readline }```, which only reads oneline.

Answer (score 7):

I get the problem! I'm having the same one. Calling `read` seems to do what you want (populates the `headers` variable):

```
data = CSV.new(file, **flags)
data.headers # => true

data = CSV.new(file, **flags).read
data.headers # => ['field1', 'field2']
```

There might be other side effects I'm not aware of, but this works for me and doesn't smell too bad.

Answer (score 6):

I don't quite get the problem. If you use one of the iterator methods, it's quite easy to do some validation on the headers:

```
CSV.foreach('tmp.txt', headers: true) do |csv| 
  return unless csv.headers[0] != 'xyz'
end
```

Comment: I don't think the file is closed if you return from the block. No? This of course assumes the file has at least one line beyond the header.